# $f,g\in R(\mathbb{T})$. How to show $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |\hat{f}(n)|<\infty$ if $\hat{f}(n)n^{2\over 3}=\hat{g}(n)$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

> Let $f,g\in R(\mathbb{T})$ s.t $\hat{f}(n)n^{2\over 3}=\hat{g}(n)$
> .Prove $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |\hat{f}(n)|<\infty$.

---

We get  $\hat{f}(n)n^{2\over 3}=\hat{g}(n) \implies \hat{f}(n)=\frac{\hat{g}(n)}{n^{2\over 3}}$
. I'm not sure how to continue or use this information.

Comment: What is $R(\mathbb T)$?

Comment: @Olius Sorry I thought it's common enough. If $f \in R(\mathbb T) $, then $\forall x: f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$ and $f$ is integrable (Riemann).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By
$$ 2ab\le a^2+b^2$$
one has
$$|\hat{f}(n)|=\frac{|\hat{g}(n)|}{n^{2\over 3}}\le\frac12|\hat{g}(n)|^2+\frac12\frac{1}{n^{4\over 3}}$$
and hence
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(n)|=|\hat{f}(0)|+\sum_{n\neq0}|\hat{f}(n)|\le|\hat{f}(0)|+\frac12\sum_{n\neq0}|\hat{g}(n)|^2+\frac12\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^{4\over 3}}\le|\hat{f}(0)|+\frac12\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{g}(n)|^2+\frac12\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^{4\over 3}}<|\hat{f}(0)|+\frac12\|g\|_2^2+\frac12\sum_{n\neq0}\frac{1}{n^{4\over 3}}<\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you!!! what made you think about this trick? and $\hat{f}(0)$ was taken out of the sum because $|\hat{f}(n)|=\frac{|\hat{g}(n)|}{n^{2\over 3}}\le\frac12|\hat{g}(n)|^2+\frac12\frac{1}{n^{4\over 3}}$ is not true for $n=0$?

Comment: Yes, you're right.